# Google plus login, Android singing in prompt is repeatedly occure while login

Tags: android, google-apps, google-api-java-client, google-signin

I am new to android development. I am integrating google plus login into my App, I am little bit confusing that the Singing in prompt of google is occurring repeatedly. I can't understand why, is anything wrong with me?

I am following [Google Developer Site](https://developers.google.com/+/quickstart/android) to make this thing. I tested the app using multiple google account but 2 of them are works fine but rest of the account did not.

Comment: Please add your code so we can help you.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried:

> How do I debug my Google+ integration?

By enabling logging, you can diagnose network issues when working with the Google APIs.

To enable logging, run the following command:

```
adb shell setprop log.tag.GooglePlusPlatform VERBOSE
```

To disable logging, run the following command:

```
adb shell setprop log.tag.GooglePlusPlatform ""
```

Permission which you have to add:

> To access Google+ APIs:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

> To retrieve the account name (email) as part of sign-in:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
```

To retrieve OAuth 2.0 tokens or invalidate tokens to disconnect a user. This disconnect option is required to comply with the Google+ Sign-In developer policies:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS" />
```

See, if that helps.

Comment: Thanks @Gaurav Dave, but it did not save me. I think it happen for not  getting the access token in first time so UserRecoverableAuthException is occure and recall the method for access token... If I am not right please tell me.

Would it be a permission issue....?

Comment: Sounds like permission issue to me.

Comment: Hi @Gaurav Dave. Would you like to tell me what permission issue this is..? I tested this using 2 google accounts, in one its working fine but in another email it does not work... So I told you about the permission issue. Is there anything I need to activate except google plus api(I have already checked google plus api) in google project console api

Comment: Have you added these permission, while using G+?

Comment: Yes , when I created this app I was.

Comment: When using G+ through different account, what error message do you get? have you used logcat to see the reponse?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69664/discussion-between-biswajitghosh-and-gaurav-dave).

Comment: No sorry I'm unable to replicate this. In android 4.4.2 there are too many logs its difficult to find the exact point. I think I'm not the first person faced this situation, have you face? How did you solve your issue can you share with me... please and thanks for stay with me.

Comment: It has been a long time, so I exactly don't remember the issue. So, is your problem solved? Where were you trying before?

Comment: Visit this: http://www.androidhive.info/2014/02/android-login-with-google-plus-account-1/ might help you, if incase you've missed any point

Answer (score 1):

```
protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
            mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
        }
    }


onCreate(Bundle bundle){
mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(YourActivity.this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(YourActivity.this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(YourActivity.this).addApi(Plus.API)
                .addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_LOGIN).build();
}



btn_gpluslogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        signInWithGplus();
                    }
                });

private void signInWithGplus() {
        if (!mGoogleApiClient.isConnecting()) {
            mSignInClicked = true;
            resolveSignInError();
        }
    }

private void resolveSignInError() {
        if (mConnectionResult.hasResolution()) {
            try {
                mIntentInProgress = true;
                mConnectionResult.startResolutionForResult(this, RC_SIGN_IN);
            } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                mIntentInProgress = false;
                mGoogleApiClient.connect();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {
        if (!result.hasResolution()) {
            GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(result.getErrorCode(), this,
                    0).show();
            return;
        }

        if (!mIntentInProgress) {
            // Store the ConnectionResult for later usage
            mConnectionResult = result;

            if (mSignInClicked) {
                // The user has already clicked 'sign-in' so we attempt to
                // resolve all
                // errors until the user is signed in, or they cancel.
                resolveSignInError();
            }
        }

    }

@Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle arg0) {
        mSignInClicked = false;
        Toast.makeText(this, "User is connected!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        // Get user's information
        SharedPreferences pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyPref", 0); // 0 - for private mode
        boolean isSignedUp = pref.getBoolean("isSignedUp", false);
        if (!isSignedUp)
            getGProfileInformation();

        // Update the UI after signin
    }

private void updateUI(boolean isSignedIn) {
        if (isSignedIn) {
            getGProfileInformation();
        } else {
            btn_gpluslogin.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Fetching user's information name, email, profile pic
     */
    private void getGProfileInformation() {
        try {
            if (Plus.PeopleApi.getCurrentPerson(mGoogleApiClient) != null) {
                Person currentPerson = Plus.PeopleApi
                        .getCurrentPerson(mGoogleApiClient);
                Log.d("Google Info", currentPerson.toString());
                String personName = currentPerson.getDisplayName();
                String email = Plus.AccountApi.getAccountName(mGoogleApiClient);

            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Person information is null", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you did not provided any code, let me guess. If you say you have problems with certain accounts and others not, it seems to me these problematic accounts have not authorized your app. Please check (while logged in a browser) this configuration:

https://security.google.com/settings/security/permissions?pli=1

Or this?

https://plus.google.com/u/0/apps

And look for your app in the list. Maybe your permissions were denied or something. Perhaps you just need to grant them again, reset and try again.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I bet is happening.

In `onConnectionFailed` you are starting the resolution from the `connectionResult`.  This then launches the Activity to resolve the failure and should return the result to `onActivityResult`.  However you need to make sure not to get into a resolution loop.

So in `onConnectionFailed`, do this:

```
private boolean mIsResolving = false;
// ...
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
  if (connectionResult.hasResolution() && !mIsResolving) {
    mIsResolving = true;
    connectionResult.startResolutionForResult(this, RC_SIGN_IN);
  }
}
```

Then in `onActivityResult` do this:

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
  super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
  if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
      mIsResolving = false;
      mGoogleApitClient.connect();
    } else {
      // ...
    }
  }
}
```